# Android layout for detaild data

Tags: android, layout

What is the name of this kind of layout? How can I achieve this kind of layout in android? Anyone please guide me if there is any tutorial available for this?

[image]

Comment: There's nothing special about this layout. The 2 panels, left and right, could be represented by 2 `LinearLayout`s that take equal amount of space horizontally. Then each of these 2 `LinearLayout`s has  other layouts placed vertically.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a multicolumn list (2-columns in your case). You can find a solution at http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/17/a-multi-column-list/